# gsub a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to get only the domain name i.e. `google.com` from javascript

```
document.location.hostname
```

This code returns `www.google.com`.

How can I only get `google.com`? In this case it would be to either remove the `www.` or get only the domain name (if there's such a method in javascript).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var host = location.hostname.replace( /www\./g, '' );
```

The 'g' flag is for 'global', which is needed if you want a true "gsub" (all matches replaced, not just the first).

Better, though, would be to get the full TLD:

```
var tld = location.hostname.replace( /^(.+\.)?(\w+\.\w+)$/, '$2' );
```

This will handle domains like `foo.bar.jim.jam.com` and give you just `jam.com`.

Answer (score 1):

...  I'm in chrome right now, and `window.location.host` does the trick.

**EDIT**

So I'm an idiot... BUT hopefully this will redeem:

An alternate to regex:

```
var host = window.location.hostname.split('.')
    .filter(
        function(el, i, array){
            return (i >= array.length - 2)
        }
    )
    .join('.');
```

Comment: I believe that's just because you're at `stackoverflow.com`, without a `www`. If you go to `www.adobe.com` and type in `javascript:alert(location.host)`, you'll see that it does not work.